# Using a variable in Django yesno template tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This could rather be straightforward. However, allow me to ask. In the Django yesno inbuilt template tag, the syntax is given as `{{ value|yesno:"yeah,no,maybe" }}`.

However, I want to out a variable value if it evaluates to true, something like: `{{ request.user.profile.mobile_number|yesno:$variable1, 'string' }}`.

I have tried this `{{ request.user.profile.mobile_number|yesno:"{{ request.user.profile.mobile_number }},No Contact" }}` but I keep on getting an error: `Could not parse the remainder: ':"{{ request.user.profile.mobile_number' from 'request.user.profile.mobile_number|yesno:"{{ request.user.profile.mobile_number'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% with yesno_args=request.user.profile.mobile_number|add:", No Contact" %}
{{ request.user.profile.mobile_number|yesno:yesno_args }}
{% endwith %}
```

Alternatively, which may be more clear:

```
{% if request.user.profile.mobile_number is not None and request.user.profile.mobile_number != '' %}
<span>{{ request.user.profile.mobile_number }}</span>
{% else %}
<span>No Contact</span>
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sure, the first option still failing, but the second option is good. I was trying to avoid long codes but it seems I have no option. Just edited your code to add double curly brackets that you forgot.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I approved your edit. Sorry that the first version didn't work!

Comment: @japheth just changed my original answer, let me know if that one works! You can also prepare `yesno_args` in the view. I didn't realize that the args had to be a string.

Comment: I was just wondering why they didn't just make it one line since it should be a shorthand, but it's a small thing to complain about than focusing on the bigger things that they have made possible. Thanks for the help buddy.

Comment: @SamCreamer in this way we would have to write long snippets for each variable we want to use with yesno. is there a way to just use the variable in argument